# Lipschitz and the spectral radius

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-radius, contraction-mapping

let's say $M_{n\times n}$ is a matrix, I know the following theorem:

> if $Mx+d=x$ has a unique solution ($x^*$) then we have: the sequence $x_0,f(x_0),f(f(x_0)),\dots$ is convergent to $x^*$ for all $x_0$ if and only if the spectral radius of M is less than $1$

if $f(x) = Mx+d$ is a contraction under the euclidean distance then that means (if we take $y$ to be zero) $\| Mx+d -M0-d\|=\|Mx\|<\|x\|$, which means $\frac{\|Mx\|}{\|x\|}<1$, therefore the spectral radius also has to be less than one.

what I want to know is the relationship between the spectral radius and the lipschitz constant(using euclidean distance). if the spectral radius is less than $1$ can I claim $f(x)$ is a contraction? can I also claim that spectral radius is the smallest possible lipschitz constant?

I know if eigenvectors of M ($v_1,\dots,v_n$) make a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}$ are its eigenvalues which I assume to be positive, then:
$(|\lambda^*|=max\{|\lambda_1|,\dots,|\lambda_n|\})$
$$\|Mx+d-My-d\|=\|M(x-y)\|=\|M(\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_nv_n)\|\\=\|\lambda_1\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\lambda_n
\alpha_nv_n\|\le|\lambda^*|\|x-y\|$$
so $f(x)$ has to be a contraction as $|\lambda^*|<1$. is this proof correct? what if the eigenvectors don't make a basis or the eigenvalues aren't positive?

Comment: The largest singular value can be much larger than the spectral radius. If you increase the spectral radius by a little bit, then you can find a norm so that the associated operator norm of $M$ will be smaller than that number.

Comment: I don't yet know what operators and singular values are. I do understand that the induced norm can be a lot greater than the spectral radius, but what about the smallest possible constant M for the lipschitz condition? is it not the case that if absolute values of all eigen values of M are less than one then f(x) is a contraction? geometrically it seems to me like spectral radius is the same thing as the smallest possible M.

Comment: Yes, that is true in principle. But you wanted to  use the Euclidean norm, and that will not work. I'm not sure if elliptical norms will work. Take the example $M=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$. The spectral radius is zero, the induced norm for the Euclidean vector norm is $1$. Using similarity transforms one can get $UMU^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&\epsilon\\0&0}$ which has operator norm $\epsilon$. Similar can also be done in the general case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is the theorem that I've given at the start false? in your counter example if we take $x_0 = (0,1)$ then the sequence $x0,f(x0),f(f(x0)),…$ doesn't converge. note that I'm assuming M satisfies the condition of the theorem meaning Mx+d=x has a unique solution, since the given sequence doesn't converge given your M and spectral radius is less than one then that would mean Mx+d = x doesn't have a unique solution, unless the theorem that we were given is false.

Comment: Try again, $f(x_0)=(1,0)$, $f(f(x_0))=(0,0)$ and stationary afterwards. The claims and theorems you cite are all correct, your thoughts about the proofs or some intuitive picture are insufficient.

Comment: I see, so in this case the smallest possible lipschitz constant(with euclidean norm) for f(x) = Mx + d would be 1 but spectral value would be zero. I think I get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion so far: The theorem is true, if $\rho(M)<1$ then the sequence converges to the fixed point.

The smallest Lipschitz constant of $f$ in the euclidean norm is the induced operator norm of $M$ is the largest singular value $\sigma_1(M)=\sqrt{\rho(M^TM)}$. As you maybe hinted at, the spectral radius is smaller than any operator norm.

Other vector norms exist, some can be constructed as $\|x\|=\|Ax\|_2$ or $\|x\|=\|Ax\|_\infty$. In the latter case $A$ can have a very high number of rows and its unit ball can approximate any point-symmetric convex shape arbitrarily closely.

Varying over all possible vector norms, it turns out that the spectral radius is the largest lower bound, even if it is not always itself contained in that set, example $M=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$. As all vector norms in finite dimension are equivalent, it is sufficient to have one induced operator norm to be smaller than $1$ to get convergence.

The example shows that the euclidean norm is not always optimal, as with $M^TM=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$ the largest singular value is $1$, while the spectral radius is $0$.

Another approximation theorem states that independent of the vector norm chosen, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\|M^n\|_{op}}=\rho(M).$$ So even with fixing the euclidean norm one can find an $n$ so that $f^n(x)$ has a Lipschitz constant smaller than $1$. It is a standard argument that under uniqueness the fixed point of $f^n$ is also the unique fixed point of $f$.